# Поиск первого элемента из списка с помощью python

Tags: html, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Вопрос следующий: Пишу автотест. Мне нужно зайти на яндекс.картинки и
1) найти Первую картинку из имеющихся, 
2) открыть её, 
3) перейти назад, 
4) опять найти первую 
5) убедиться, что это одна и та же картинка (из шага 2)

Пока нашел:

```
    from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\trash\\Python projects\\chromedriver.exe")
sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://yandex.ru")
sleep(2)
a: WebElement=driver.find_element_by_link_text("Картинки")
assert a, ("ОПА")##Проверка что есть картинки
a.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)
b: WebElement=driver.find_element_by_class_name("cl-teaser[1]")          
b.click()
sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("layout__nav__left")
c: WebElement=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.masonry__column:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1").click()
assert b
```

Comment: Вам нужен URL первой картинки?

Comment: мне нужно найти первую и открыть её.

Comment: открыть саму картинку или кликнуть на элемент, чтобы открылось всплывающее окно?

Comment: открыть саму картинку. т.е. в целом получается - 1) найти Первую картинку из имеющихся, 2) открыть её, 3) закрыть, 4) опять найти первую и 5)убедиться, что это одна и та же картинка (из шага  2)

Comment: Давайте мы начнём с того, какой URL вы посещаете. Потому что я вам возможно подскажу одну особенность. Яндекс.Картики без поискового слова, это один сайт, а с ведённым словом, это уже другой сайт. Грубо говоря, URL один, а вёрстка разная. Поэтому больше подробностей в вопрос пожалуйста, тогда мы сможем вам помочь

Comment: Судя по `cl-picture__image` вы посещаете сайт без ввода поискового слова. Если так, то у меня вопрос - между посещениями, вы сессию начинаете заного? То есть - или новый `webdriver.driver` (новая сессия) или чистите следы (куки и хранилища канваса и прочие) или вы заходите на сайт одним экземпляром браузера, раз в какой-то промежуток времени? От этого зависит то, что выведет вам Яндекс

Comment: И конечно же, какой xPath вы пробовали? Я задаю этот вопрос, потому что вероятно вы не смогли написать работающий xpath в силу не знания особенностей его составления. Поэтому, допишите в свой вопрос тот xpath который вы попробовали

Comment: изменил код... падает на driver.find_element_by_class_name("layout__nav__left")

Comment: ("layout__nav__left")  - вроде кнопка "Назад", но что-то не так..

Answer (score 0):

Можно искать элементы `<img class="cl-picture__image">`

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://images.yandex.ru')

image = driver.find_element_by_class_name('cl-picture__image')
print(image.get_attribute('src'))
```